# insert() function with items in reverse order

Tags: python, function, insert

I'm new to python and want to learn everything about it. There's something I don't understand for the following given code snippet:

```
list = []
for i in range(5):
    list.insert(0,i+1)
print(list)
```

Why does insert(**0**, i+1) gives the same output as append(i+1), but in the reverse order? I don't understand the syntax / reason behind using just a 0 separated by a comma. Every idea is welcome!

Edit: I don't see any difference between the append method, which inserts 0 1 2 3 4 5 at the end of the list and insert(0,i+1), which inserts the same thing at the start of the list. The list is empty, how does it come, that they are in reverse order ?

Comment: It does not. `insert(i+1)` will throw an error, because the `.insert` method requires two arguments.

Comment: This code inserts the new item at the _beginning_ of the list (i.e. position 0).

Comment: See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for instance. `list.insert`'s first argument tells you where an item is to be inserted, so your code inserts each new item at the start of the list. If you had `append(i + 1)`, it would indeed give you the same list but in the reverse order.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I initially had the same comment. I think the questioner meant `append(i+1)` instead of `insert(i+1)`.

Comment: My bad. Yes, I mean why does it do the same job as append(i+1), but in the reserve order

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I don't get it. If I insert something at the 0 start point, why I get 5 4 3 2 1 and not 1 2 3 4 5? I don't see the difference to append(i+1), even if append inserts to the last item.

Comment: `.append(x)` means "add x at the end".  `.insert(0, x)` means "push all the elements down one spot and add x at the beginning".  Of course those two methods will produce different results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python documentation explains this 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=insert

In any case this ( https://docs.python.org/3/ ) is a good place to search, though sometimes searching in stack overflow might return an easy to understand faster

`list.insert(pos, val)` inserts the value `val` before position `pos`

inserting before position 0 means, the element to insert will be the first element of the list.

whereas `a.append(x)` (which is equivalent to `a.insert(len(a), x)`) appends the new element at the end of the list.

Therefore the order is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get this at first either so I ended up asking the code to reveal the list construction in the loop for me. I added a print statement inside the loop to show me each iteration:

```
my_list = [] # Start with an empty list

for i in range(5):
    my_list.insert(0, i + 1)
    print(my_list)

[1]
[2, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

After adding 1 to the list, the next element pushes 1 to the right to insert 2 and so on and so forth. The end result is a list in reverse order. Hope that helps.